# WiFi stopped working on Windows 10 while I was using laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a 7 year old HP ProBook laptop which is my daily driver. Just now I was using laptop and all of a sudden WiFi stopped working. The network icon on task bar is in disconnect state and it says "no internet access"

I have done the following but no luck. Is this hardware issue and my WiFi adapter is actually gone forever?

1. Turn on/off airplane mode
2. Turn on/off WiFi
3. Restarting laptop
4. Doing 'Network reset' option which is available in 'settings --> nerwork & internet --> status', then shutting down laptop and start.
5. Running commands 'netsh winsock reset' and 'netsh int ip reset' and then restarting.

I can see WiFi access points available and if I try to connect to anyone, it asks me password but after that it doesn't connect.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide specifics about your device.  We need to know at least the laptop's model number so we can verify a device driver has been released for Windows 10, but we also need to know, what version of Windows 10 you are running.  A driver released for 1507 3 years ago is unlikely to result in a working device if you have 1909 installed.  The fact it did work, indicates your system recently installed a feature update, which means this is a driver compatibility issue.

Comment: You might try disabling bluetooth in the device manager. The wifi and bluetooth are often on the same chip package in laptops and I have resolved wifi speed and connectivity issues in the past by disabling it.

Comment: Laptop is HP ProBook 4540s. WiFi is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 802.11bgn.

Comment: I have another USB WiFi adapter lying around and even that one is not working. It is 802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card.

Comment: Have you recently had a Windows 10 upgrade to version 1909?

Comment: My version is 1803 (OS Build 17134.1130). Disabling bluetooth driver didnt fix the issue.

Comment: (1) Make sure other Wifi devices connected to the same AP works, or its the AP/Router's problem instead of your NB. (2) Try power cycleing your AP/router. (3) Make sure you can't ping the router, or its the internet's problem insead of Wifi. (4) Check the Wifi NIC in Device Manager, check any error/warnings, try disable/enable, try delete/reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Wireless card driver. Go to the HP Support site for your model, get the newest driver and install it. If it will not install, that indicates a hardware issue. Otherwise, restart and test the connection.

Comment: In device manager, driver is in OK state and when I try to update driver, it says latest driver is already installed.

Comment: Try again the reset and add the reset log: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt   . Sometimes you need to add the log for this command to work

Comment: I ran above command but it didnt generate any log file although the command completed successfully. I also downloaded and installed WiFi driver from HP website but no luck.

Comment: OK so now you may consider a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Answer (score 0):

I turned on laptop after around 7 hours and ran `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` command again and noticed it was showing access denied error in one of the lines. May be it was also showing last night and I didn't notice. Then I applied following solution which fixed the issue:

https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/netsh-int-ip-reset-says-access-denied/

1. Open Regedit.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi` and expand that folder.
3. Expand the subfolder named `{eb004a00-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}` and right-click the subfolder named `26`. Select Permissions… and ensure that for Everyone the Full Control box is checked.
4. Run `netsh int ip reset` again
5. Reboot the system.

After rebooting I also did following steps:

1. Enabled bluetooth driver in device manager (I had disabled it last night)
2. Uninstalled WiFi driver and then did `Scan for hardware changes` in device manager which installed WiFi driver again automatically
3. After that I was able to connect to WiFi